# Get an injected dependency in a non-Angular class

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have the current (& simplified) class :

```
export class NavigationItem {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  navigateTo() { this.router.navigate([this.id]); }
}
```

I would like not to have to inject myself the router everytime I declare a new instance of this class.

Is there a way of doing so ? I thought about something along the lines of

```
export class NavigationItem {

  @Inject(forwardRef(() => Router))
  private _router: Router;

  constructor() {}

  navigateTo() { this.router.navigate([this.id]); }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea ?

Comment: You could create a factory that you register with DI and use that to create instances of `NavigationItem` - the factory could depend on `Router` and wire up your new `NavigationItem` instances to it.

Comment: I thought about using factories, but my initial goal is to be able to create classes that don't need to be declared into a module (either through a factory or an injection), yet can get dependencies of the current project. Picture this : I would like to be able to move those classes between project, and only those classes ; with a factory, I'd have to rewrite the same factory in the next project ! (or import the module with the factory, but you get the point, I want to only move the classes)

Comment: You could declare it as a static property, and define it once at the start of the application.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I also tried that by declaring a static property into the root module, but then again, it requires me to create a static member on every project ...

Comment: I mean: a static property of `NavigationItem`. You would initialize it from another class that does inject `router` (like `AppComponent`).

Comment: With `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` on the factory class, you wouldn't need to declare either the factory or the item class itself into a module.

Comment: @ConnorsFan potato potato, that's the same principle in the reverse direction, it still requires me to write code in another project ...

Comment: @KirkLarkin but that would create a provider, and my classes should be instances that I can tamper with (for instance, navigation items are the items of my sidenav menu, providing them into the root module would create a singleton, woudn't it ?)

Comment: Looking at the nice answer by @KirkLarkin, you can imagine a service that sets a static `router` property in `NavigationItem`. (1) It would not involve the constructor of `NavigationItem`, (2) it would not require more "code in another project" than the factory. It may actually involve less code if you inject that service only in the application component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a factory service that handles creation of `NavigationItem`s and wires them up with the `Router`. Here's an example of what a `NavigationItemFactory` class might look like:

```
// imports

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class NavigationItemFactory {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    createItem(): NavigationItem {
        return new NavigationItem(this.router);
    }
}
```

Because this uses Angular 6+'s `providedIn` feature, you don't need to declare this factory class in a module, which makes it easily movable between projects.

Anywhere you want to create these items in your project, just take a dependency on `NavigationItemFactory` and use its `createItem` function accordingly. Granted, this is a still a dependency you'll need in your project but at least it's now a dependency on your own type rather than `Router` itself.

Comment: Altough it doesn't really answer the question I have asked (still in the constructor), it's a nice workaround and I'll use that for now. Thank you for this, I didn't think about it like that !

Comment: No problem at all. Please do come back and post your own answer if you manage to find something more appropriate. I also suggest being a bit more explicit in the question about not wanting to use the constructor as that might help other answerers.